# Adding UI elements to a PFQueryTableViewController/UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I was curious as to if I was able to override the appeareance of how a `PFQueryTableViewController` looks (not the cells or table itself). For example right now I am adding my search bar programatically to the header of my tableView. The issue I'm having with that is when the user scrolls the tableView the header goes up with it, and I want it to stick. I know I can easily probably accomplish this by making a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`, but was wondering if there is any way to add this above the tableview in a PFQueryTableViewController (subclass of `UITableViewController` I believe if I'm not total noob?), or get the header to stick?

Here is how I currently have my searchBar adding to my PFQueryTableViewController in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
  UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
  searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
  searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

  self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
  [[UISearchBar appearance]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
  self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
  self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

  [self.searchController.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"What are you looking for?"];
```